# What could be the cause of "java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 0 failed"

Tags: android, sql, exception, sqlite

I have an SQL query running on an 'sqlite' database that is throwing this exception: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 0 failed" when I call:

```
db.rawQuery( "SELECT data FROM session_data WHERE session_id = ?", new String[] { String.format("%d", session_id) } );
if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) return;
bytes[] bytes = cursor.getBlob(0);
```

The column exists, and if I log in using `adb shell sqlite3 /path/to/database.db` I can successfully execute the same query.

The resulting cursor shows that there is 1 row selected with 1 column whose name is "data". The size of the blob is about 1.5 MB - could that be it? I have verified that `cursor.GetColumnIndex("data")` returns 0, so the column exists.

This is running on Android 2.1 SDK. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the blob was too big. It appears that `cursor.getBlob(0)` fails if the blob size is over a megabyte. Reading the blob in segments solved my issue:

```
// get length of blob data
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery( "SELECT LENGTH(data) AS len FROM table WHERE id = ?", etc);
if (cursor == null || !cursor.moveToFirst()) throw new Exception("failed");
int size = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("len"));
cursor.close();

// read a segment of the blob data
cursor = db.rawQuery( "SELECT SUBSTR(data,0,500000) AS partial FROM table WHERE id = ?", etc);
if (cursor == null || !cursor.moveToFirst()) throw new Exception("failed");
byte[] partial = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("partial"));
cursor.close();

// copy partial bytes, repeat until the whole length has been read...
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are holding a reference to the cursor from the `rawQuery`.
Before you get any value from the cursor you need to call `cursor.moveToFirst()` because the `cursor` is initially positioned at -1. The correct way would be:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery( "SELECT data FROM session_data WHERE session_id = ?", new String[] { String.format("%d", session_id) } );
if(cursor!= null && cursor.moveToFirst()){ // checking if the cursor has any rows
   bytes[] bytes = cursor.getBlob(0);
}
```

and also make sure that your column in the database is `blob` type

Comment: I was actually doing this - I've updated the question. Thanks.