# openContactPhotoInputStream causes “java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 0 failed”

Tags: android, blob, android-contacts, illegalstateexception

### Background

I'm trying to check if a contact image exists for a specific contact (and later to actually get it, much later). the query should be as minimal as possible and avoid un-needed memory usage.

I've figured out this probably isn't possible using the normal way, so for now I'm using:

```
final Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, contactKey);
final Cursor contactCur = mContentResolver.query(lookupUri, new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID },
        null, null, null);
if (contactCur == null)
    return false;
contactCur.moveToFirst();
long contactId = 0;
if (contactCur.getCount() != 0)
    contactId = contactCur.getLong(contactCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
contactCur.close();
if (contactId == 0)
    return false;
final Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);

final InputStream inputStream;
if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(mContext.getContentResolver(),
            contactUri, bigPicture);
else
    inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(mContext.getContentResolver(),
            contactUri);
if (inputStream != null) {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
    return true;
}
return false;
```

### The problem

It seems like on some rare cases, devices return me an exception of :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 0
>   failed at android.database.CursorWindow.getBlob_native(Native Method)
>   at android.database.CursorWindow.getBlob(CursorWindow.java:288) at
>   android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getBlob(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:35)
>   at android.database.CursorWrapper.getBlob(CursorWrapper.java:143) at
>   android.provider.ContactsContract$Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(ContactsContract.java:1174)

as it turns out, there are plenty of reports on this issue, but not regarding "openContactPhotoInputStream" function.

from what I've read (for example [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6103365/878126)), it is caused since the blob that need to be read is too large, but in this case, I have this problem within Android's code...

### The question

What's the best way to overcome this?

Is it possible it's a bug on Android?

My guess is that even if I use try-catch , when I try to get the image later I would get the same error, right?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this for checking if a photo exists (untested):

```
ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();
if (bigPicture && VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    Uri displayPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO);
    AssetFileDescriptor fd = null;
    try {
        fd = cr.openAssetFileDescriptor(displayPhotoUri, "r");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    if (fd != null) {
        try {
            fd.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
}

Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
Cursor cursor = cr.query(photoUri, new String[] {BaseColumns._ID},
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.PHOTO + " IS NOT NULL", null, null);
if (cursor == null) {
    return false;
}
try {
    return cursor.moveToFirst();
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

And here is a modified version of the `openContactPhotoInputStream()` method, which should potentially be able to load a photo thumbnail with a size close to 1 MB without issues (again not tested):

```
public static InputStream openContactPhotoInputStream(ContentResolver cr, Uri contactUri,
        boolean preferHighres) {
    if (preferHighres && VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        Uri displayPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO);
        try {
            return cr.openAssetFileDescriptor(displayPhotoUri, "r").createInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
    Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    try {
        return cr.openAssetFileDescriptor(displayPhotoUri, "r").createInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

This should cause the `ContactsProvider` to read the thumbnail `BLOB` to shared memory, and send an `AssetFileDescriptor` pointing to it, from which we can directly open an `InputStream`.

Comment: is opening a fileDescriptor using the "DISPLAY_PHOTO" the same as the method of using an inputStream?  does it somehow avoids the issue i've mentioned? is it possible to make a query without opening any files ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: This code was copied from the `openContactPhotoInputStream()` method implementation, but modified to only query whether the data exits in the `PHOTO` column instead of querying for the photo `BLOB` itself. It also avoids unnecessarily opening the `InputSteam` from the `AssetFileDescriptor` in the case of the high-res photo file query. Since this code is not reading a large `BLOB` from a `Cursor`, it should fix the issue you are encountering.

Comment: I see. sadly this is a very rare bug, so I won't be able to know if it fixes anything after a long time. hope i will remember to tick it if it's correct. thank you for your time. for now, you will get an upvote instead of ticking... :)

Comment: @androiddeveloper: You can see from the code itself that it fixes your issue :) The exception was caused by the `openContactPhotoInputStream()` method calling `getBlob()` on the `Cursor`, and you can see that nowhere in my solution do I have a call to `getBlob()`. There might be some other issue with the code as it isn't tested, but that issue should have been fixed. But it's fine if you want to wait and test before accepting it.

Comment: but will i be able to read the photo afterwards? as i've written, i have 2 steps with long time-gap between them : one for quereing about the photo, and one for getting it. wouldn't i get this exception when trying to read the photo?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: I only provided a solution for the code you posted. For actually loading the photo, you will still need to call `openContactPhotoInputStream()`. I don't think there is a solution to the 1 MB limit on reading `BLOB`s from `Cursor`s; the best you can do is catch the `IllegalStateException`, and load a default photo or get the high-res photo if you are post-ICS.

Comment: so android has an issue of reading large things using blob ? wonder how they've missed it.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: This is a limitation of Android's IPC transaction protocol; it's memory buffer has a 1 MB limit. `CursorWindow` is populated dynamically, but it can't hold more than 1 MB at once because of this.

Comment: in which cases do you think this occurs for getting the contact photo? does it mean it happens when the compressed image data is more than 1MB ? also, why did they save the image data within the DB? isn't it wiser to put it into files, and have a URI of some sort to them within the DB in order to make it small?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: Storing `BLOB`s smaller than 100 KB in SQLite gives greater read performance than storing them in the filesystem, so the `ContactsProvider` schema stores thumbnails directly to the database, while storing only a file-system reference to high-res photos. Unfortunately, the provider doesn't seem to enforce any size constraints in the `PHOTO` column, so sync adapters are free to store photos up to 1 MB in the column. My guess is that the photo `BLOB` may fail to load if the size of the thumbnail is close to 1 MB.

Comment: I see. So it's a bug on the OS of some sort. Still I think it might be better to have small DB (or maybe 2 DB files- images and the rest) instead.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: As far as I know, there is no inherent performance advantage in keeping an SQLite database to a small size.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: I have added a potential solution for getting around the 1 MB limitation of loading the thumbnail from a Cursor.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: As I said in the edit, it's not tested; it's just something I put together after looking through the `ContactsProvider` implementation. You can test it out if you want, and report back if there are any issues.